# Int SQL variable takes value 1 in .Net when format changed to bigint in SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm using for my project ASP.NET MVC 3 and SQL SERVER 2008.
The stored procedures are declared with Entity Framework.

I have already some SQL Stored Procedures successfuly called from .Net but get a strange behavior on one of them ...

### SQL Part :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPD_OR_CRE] 
    @ID int, -- Create element if null, update if not null
    @other_paramters ...,
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; -- I also tried with OFF : same effect

Declare 
@result int,
@resultbigint bigint;

IF (@ID is not null)
    BEGIN
     -- @ID is not null => update
        BEGIN TRY
        update TABLE
        set
        ...
        where ID = @ID
        ;
        set @result = @ID;
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
        -- catching some error.
        END CATCH;
    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
    -- @ID is null => create
    exec @result = CREATE_FUNCTION ... ; 

    -- CREATE_FUNCTION return the new ID

    -- set @result = 56; -- hard coded for test
    END

-- I put here for test a write in a journal table : @result is always correct
select @result "RESULT";
END
```

---

### .Net part :

```
Int32? iD = null;
ObjectResult<Nullable<global::System.Int32>> coll = _db.UPD_OR_CRE(parameters ...);

iD = coll.ElementAt(0);
```

---

The work is always done by the stored procedure (update or create), when I call for an update, I can get back the iD in .Net (the same one than when calling in this case), when I call for a create, I always get iD = 1 in .NET and this even if I hard code for example with "set @result = 56;" after the CREATE_FUNCTION.

When I delete the CREATE_FUNCTION call, the hard coded result come to .Net (here 56 for example).

I think the problem could came from Integer formats (in some cases @result is changed for bigint in CREATE_FUNCTION, but its value always remain int compliant), but I made a lot of other tests to convert back @result to an Int without success (and I still don't understand why it's returning "1" in this case ..). Example of these tests with

---

```
exec @resultbigint = CREATE_FUNCTION ... ;
-- (one of the following lines)
set @result = (select cast(cast(@resultbigint as varchar) as int));
set @result = convert(int,@resultbigint);
set @result = (select cast(@resultbigint as int));
```

---

Of course the answer could be to rewrite the CREATE_FUNCTION to get Int in return but this involves a lot of other work ...

Any help, track or ideas would be appreciated ...

Philippe

Comment: create_function is a stored procedure right?

Comment: @Daisy : Yes, "CREATE_FUNCTION" is a stored procedure returning the ID of the created element (or -1 if error, ...).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. It isn't a format problem.

In one of the called procedure (behind CREATE_FUNCTION) it was a request for a table access testing (something like "select top 1 from table" in a try catch)

The problem occured until I changed this request for one with an affectation (something like "select @toto = count(*) from table" in same try catch)

Seems that SQL Server is not capable to manage many simple select in a set of stored procedures at least when the call is done from .Net;

Answer (score 0):

im no guru of the Databases but if just for testing you modify the else part of your stored procedure like

```
ELSE
    BEGIN
     Begin tran
      --exec @result = CREATE_FUNCTION ... ; 
      insert into Table(COL) values('someValue')

      if @@error <>0
        begin
          rollback
        end

      set @result = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
     commit
    END

select @result "RESULT";
```

your problem will be resolved

Comment: Thanks but ... I have no Identity column in my database (I like to manage my IDs myself ...) and of course the stored procedure CREATE_FUNCTION does more than only an "insert into" ...